# How android drawable automatically change?

Tags: android, drawable

I have a android application, that uses many images. and application is to be used on different resolutions. I am using only one set of images  and images are saved in "drawable-mdpi". 
So  "The images gets blur when I run it on a high resolution". 
So probably the solution of this is to save different images of different resolution in drawable-hdpi,ldpi etc.

Is doing this is enough or do I have to change the images by code? or phone automatically adjust the perfact image into the drawables.

can anybody provide a example??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put the images in the `ldpi,mdpi,hdpi` or `xhdpi` folders Android chooses the images according to the current device dpi.

If you only add `mdpi` ressources and load them on a `hdpi` device Android will enlarge the images with a factor of `1.5` if you open them on a `ldpi` device they will be shrunk with a factor of `0.75`. 
The scaling is applied so that the images have (almost) the same physical size all displays with any dpi.

You should add different images for each dpi if those images will be blurry (or loose details when shrinked) after this autoscaling. If you have simple images that look well after scaling you only need to add one image to any dpi folder.

EDIT:
On Android there is no default way for automatically selecting images depending on the screen resolution. As the docs says:

> When adding support for multiple screens, applications do not work directly with resolution; applications should be concerned only with screen size and density, as specified by the generalized size and density groups.

(see [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)).

Comment: but in my app only drawable-mdpi is used .at different resolution also . ( I write only one main.xml file in layout.)

Comment: If you use only the mdpi folder for your images they will be enlarged on hdpi and xhdpi devices and shrunk on ldpi devices. You never need to create multiple layouts. Android selects the image from the dpi folders automatically. If you i.e. use hdpi and mdpi folder, hdpi devices most probably will select the hdpi version of the images.

Comment: I have a app in which all drawable have different image but with same name, when i am using that image in layout using ImageView ,only drawable-mdpi is used . on different resolutions also .. so what may be the problem??

Comment: Do you mean resulution? You cannot add images that will be selected depending on a resolution by Android - just dpi (and some other parameters)

Comment: yes I mean resolution.I want to change images automatically  when they go to the higher dpi.

Comment: gr8 answer but still it doesn't working , maybe this is the problem that i am using emulator for this. Let me try it on real device.

Answer (score 4):

This is enough. This is the reason for having different folders in the drawable directory, but note that Android 1.5 supports only 1 folder called drawable with no subdirectories (but there are no phones on 1.5 with resolution higher than mdpi)

Comment: You may also consider xlarge screens for tablets (creating an xhdpi folder in drawable)

Comment: I have a app in which all drawable have different image but with same name, when i am using that image ,only drawable-mdpi is used . on different resolutions also .. so what may be the problem??

Comment: You test this on the emulator or actual mobiles?

Comment: If you are sure that each emulator has a different resolution, then this should work. Do not forget that the dpi refers to the density of the pixels (number of pixels divided by screen width or height). A work around is to create a layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi folders in res folder and set different images for each layout, but make sure first that you have different screen densities in the emulator as again, what you mentioned should work

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways of making sure your images are always properly scaled is to use 9 Patch drawables. Android will scale these according to the screen size automatically. They are best used for things that usually change size (Buttons, EditTexts, Spinners, etc), but can be applied properly in the right setting.

One advantage using 9 Patch images gives us is space-saving; having three different versions of images built into our applications can get quite large after awhile, but with 9 Patches you only need one copy.

See here for more details: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Hey you  are right. please provide me one 9 patch image if you can.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You create your own 9 patch images using any photo editor (Photoshop, GIMP, etc.) by expanding your image by a 1 pixel border. Within this border, you draw a black line along sections of the image that you want to scale. If you don't want to do this manually, you can use Google's draw9patch tool within the SDK. Open up a terminal window, navigate to where you have the SDK saved on your computer and run the program "draw9patch". You will be presented with an interactive window in which you can draw lines around the border of your image and watch them scale.