# Android development - Drawable images resolution, how to export?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, drawable

So, I am just a beginner and I already went trough android documentations about supporting different screen sizes and I understand most of it.
For my app, I created different layouts for each screen sizes and on the emulator it looks good.

Just one question.

How should I export images to my drawable hdpi.lpdi,...mdpi...folders? 
Because, What I did was, I used art text2, and created a project with 700x700. Well. I set it to transperant, so it's not excatly 700x700px. cause the image does not fill the entire space.

So, before I hit export, should I change the PX Resolution for example for 450x450 or something for mdpi? But, I didn't do that, and I amnot sure if I should have done that. then i hit export and it asks me where i want it to save the image. It also gives the me option to the change the DPI Resolution in DPI, i changed to 160 and saved that in my drawable/mdpi folder. But I did not change PIXEL resoultion.

So, was it correnct? or should I have changed the pixel resoultion before, I export the actual image?

In Eclipse, However, I change the width and height of the image in dp not px. so it doesn't take the entire screen space.

I checked my app  on different screen  sizes in Eclipse and it looks awesome. But, in the emulator, it looks cool. HOWEVER, if open my hdpi emulator the image does not look very sharp or clear. What's the problem?

The image itself looks clear and sharp if open it with my image viewer on my computer even, the image viewer window is almost taking the entire screen of my laptop (14,1280*800).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggeset you to use 9patch image. you can create 9patch image using android tool called draw9patch Located in sdk/tools.What you have to, create a high resolution image and then give to draw9patch tool it create image with extension .9.png and use that image 
See the link for detail

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: but, do i have to use ?

Comment: If i don't miss understood you, you are complainting about image quality in high resolution devcies. This approach will solve that problem

Comment: but it's very complicated for me, do you a know a good tutorial? google's looks complicated for me!

Comment: check this link for 9patch tutorial
http://codesignature.com/how-to-design-9-patch-buttons-for-android-using-adobe-photoshop-for-all-pixel-densities-and-states/

Answer (score 0):

Okay if i understood right, then you need to have 4 res for each image, and the aspect ratio will be "1:1.5:2:3" and some times "1:1.5:2:3:4" so you have to get all the images that you need in 3 or 4 sizes and let the android os properties do its magic by choosing the right picture based on the screen size.

Comment: but which resolution should I use when i open photoshop?

Comment: can you say an example for this ratio, you said? like if i use 700x700?

Comment: which resolution, should I use when I open Photo SHop?

Comment: first you have to check the resolution of the screen you are working with,and after that you can calculate it, for example you are using a device with screen resolution of 840*480 then the 700*700 will look like a square in that screen unless you use fill parent for the imageview.

Comment: my point is that its up to your judgment whether or not to choose the resolution of an image, if 840*480 is your screen res multiply your res by 1.5, if more than that times 2 and so on.

Comment: but, there are millions of different screen sizes. so which resolution should I use for a image when I open Photo shop?

Comment: xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

look at this carefully, and you can also read this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984848/how-android-drawable-automatically-change?rq=1

Comment: and dont forget to select the useful answer.

Comment: i know, i should do what you say, but if What I did works good on my phones, I tested on them, and all of them looks cool. because I creeated a very high resolution image, and in eclipse for each screen size layouts, I changed the width and height and it works now. Do you think I should just leave it and publish it to the markat, if i tested my app on many differnt screen sizes and looks cool to me?

Comment: there is no problem with that, but you have to keep tracking the app for feedback, and to be able to update it if anything goes wrong.